# SVG icon won't fill colour on active

Tags: html, css

I have an svg element that won't fill to a specific colour on active state. I tried looking for examples online but couldn't find much related to the subject, most of the stuff online is related to the hover state for an SVG, I tried using that method but for some reason I can't seem to target my SVG.

The active state works fine on the element background and typography but won't target my SVG.

If something is unclear please let me know, many thanks!

I created a fiddle which you can find [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rsrsrs/6dkp60a9/)

However I will put the code here for better visibility, I did simplify the code as much as I could due to other elements being in there and didn't want to confuse anyone.

My HTML:

```
<div id="contact">

  <div class="contact_Me">

    <div id="contact_Phone3_Wrapper_mb">

        <a href="tel:+xxxxxxxxxxx">

          <h3 class="contact_Me_Line_mb">

              <div class="contact_Box_Svg_1_mb">
                  <svg version="1.1" id="phone"      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"                   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                   width="15px" height="15px" viewBox="0 0 15 15" enable-background="new 0 0 15 15" xml:space="preserve">
              <path id="call" opacity="0.4" fill="#444444" d="M12.965,0.042H2.994c-0.61,0-1.108,0.499-1.108,1.108v12.741
                  c0,0.609,0.499,1.108,1.108,1.108h9.971c0.61,0,1.11-0.499,1.11-1.108V1.15C14.073,0.541,13.575,0.042,12.965,0.042 M7.979,14.818
                  c-0.359,0-0.65-0.291-0.65-0.65c0-0.357,0.292-0.65,0.65-0.65c0.36,0,0.651,0.293,0.651,0.65
                  C8.631,14.527,8.339,14.818,7.979,14.818 M12.411,13.337H3.563H3.548V1.704h8.863V13.337z"/>
              </svg>
              </div>

              <span class="contact_Small_Caps_mb">call:</span>

              <span id="contact_Phone_mb">+XX XXX XXX XX XX</span>

          </h3>

        </a>

    </div>

</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#contact_mb {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background: white;
    margin-top: 30em;
    padding-top: 2em;
    background: #e7e7e7;
}


#contact_Phone3_Wrapper_mb {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: .3em;
    background-color: rgba(249,249,249,.3);
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
 }

#contact_Phone3_Wrapper_mb:active {
   background-color: yellow;
}

#contact_Phone3_Wrapper_mb:active h3, #contact_Phone3_Wrapper_mb:active      .contact_Small_Caps_mb {
  color: #262626;
}

#contact_Phone3_Wrapper_mb:active #call {
  fill: #262626;
}

.contact_Me_Line_mb {
    color: rgba(68,68,68,.4);
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding-left: 0em;
}

.contact_Box_Svg_1_mb {
      float: left;
      width: 15px;
      height: 15px;
      margin-top: 4px;
      margin-left: 14px;
      margin-right: 12px;
    }

.contact_Small_Caps_mb {
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-family: times;
    font-size: .8em;
    margin-right: 4px;
    color: rgba(68,68,68,.2);
}

#contact_Phone_mb {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: .7em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It does work, but the color isn't really coming through, since the SVG has an opacity of 0.4.

So add `opacity: 1` to the active state of the `#call` SVG.

```
#contact_Phone3_Wrapper_mb:active #call {
    fill: #262626;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6dkp60a9/1/)